# Adding the Dynamic content in ADF V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to add Dynamic content to the file name which should be last day of the month. For Example if i run the job in April it should generate the file name as last day of the March.

Expected result be in the following format.

20190331.csv.zip

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this in your blob filename

```
@concat(formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),mul(int(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd')),-1)),'yyyyMMdd'),'.csv.zip')
```

get the day bit from `utcnow`, turn to an `int`, `mul` tiply it by -1, `adddays` the negative number to `utcnow` and then `formatdatetime` as yyyyMMdd then `concat` with whatever you want on the end

Comment: NB: if you run it on the last day of the month and you want it to say today on those occasions then you'll have to do something else in there bit more complicated

Comment: no problems, can you mark the answer as correct please, it would make me very happy :D